# Bash script - Generating random integers and writing to file

Tags: bash, random

I am trying to generate a large amount of random integers and I want to write them to a text file, which will then be used as a standard input for a C program then re-do that process but with a larger amount of random integers.

**This is what I currently have:**

```
declare -a numbers=(100 1000 10000 20000 30000 40000 50000); 

for number in ${numbers[*]}
do
    for z in $(seq 1 $number)
    do
        shuf -i 0-99 -n 1 >> tests.txt
        echo '\n' >> tests.txt
    done
    ksm.exe 50 < tests.txt
done 
exit 0
```

I currently have a couple of issues. Firstly each random value is not being placed onto a new line in the text file which is necessary for my program. Secondly the process of generating random numbers is very slow, is there a quicker method of doing this? I am a beginner in regards to Bash so i'm not quite sure if I've approached this problem in the correct way, so any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You know about `/dev/urandom`, right?

Comment: No, but i'll look into it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One **shuf** process is started at each **for** loop iteration: 151100 shuf processes are run.

Replace the **for** with a AWK script which contains **printf** and **\n** for new lines:

The AWK script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  srand();
  i=1;
  while (i++<=ENVIRON["MAXNUMBER"]) {
    printf("%d\n",int(rand()*99 + 0.5));
  }
  exit;
}
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x script.awk
```

> Note that MAXNUMBER shell variable is used to pass parameters to AWK script.

Change the original shell script, **awk** will be run 7 times:

```
declare -a numbers=(100 1000 10000 20000 30000 40000 50000); 
for number in ${numbers[*]}
do
  MAXNUMBER=$number ./script.awk >> tests.txt
  ksm.exe 50 < tests.txt
done 
exit 0
```

The test duration is 237 milliseconds with a simple echo:

```
time ./script.sh 
ksm.exe 50 < tests.txt
ksm.exe 50 < tests.txt
ksm.exe 50 < tests.txt
ksm.exe 50 < tests.txt
ksm.exe 50 < tests.txt
ksm.exe 50 < tests.txt
ksm.exe 50 < tests.txt  

real    0m0.237s
user    0m0.213s
sys     0m0.026s

wc -l tests.txt 
151100 tests.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to stick with `bash`, there is internal function called `RANDOM` which returns a int range from 0 - 32767.

```
~ % echo $RANDOM 
1287
~ % echo $RANDOM
8161
~ % echo $RANDOM
28791
```

Check the documentation here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html

==== UPDATE for actual solution ====

So in the loop, you can do `printf "$RANDOM/n" >> tests.txt`, something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a numbers=(100 1000 10000 20000 30000 40000 50000)

for number in ${numbers[*]}
do
  for ((i=0;i<$number;i++))
  do
    # generates number from 0-99
    printf "$((RANDOM*99/32767))\n" >> tests.txt
  done
  ksm.exe 50 < tests.txt
done
```

==== UPDATE for better performance ====

Thanks @Jay

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a numbers=(100 1000 10000 20000 30000 40000 50000)

function get_randoms {
  for ((i=0;i<$1;i++))
  do
    # generates number from 0-99
    printf "$((RANDOM*99/32767))\n"
  done
}

for number in ${numbers[*]}
do
  printf "$(get_randoms $number)" >> tests.txt
  ksm.exe 50 < tests.txt
done
```

Previous one takes ~14s on my laptop and the updated one takes ~3s.

Comment: Thanks, ill give this a try as well.

Comment: The bash shell is slower than awk apparently: test duration of this bash version is 10 times slower than the other ones with the awk script. This bash version has only one printf built-in command in the second **for** loop, so this result surprised me.

Comment: @Jay good find, the reason why the BASH script is much slower is it writes to the `tests.txt` file every time a new random is generated. In your AWK code, it writes to the file (PIPE) for every 100 1000 10000 ... (the MAXNUMBER) random numbers.